# Guitar that gives the best harmonics

Tags: guitar, harmonics, temperament

I'm trying to learn just intonation and was recommended by my harmony/theory teacher to use a guitar's harmonics for doing so since 1. it's easy to tune the strings and 2. produce the harmonics.

Can anyone recommend a guitar that has the "best" harmonics, i.e. 1. easiest to produce 2. longest sustain 3. cleanest sound?

Since it's for learning theory/harmony, budget instruments are preferable.

Answer (score 3):

The closer to the bridge you pluck, the better defined will be any harmonic. The smaller the fingerprint on the node, the better defined will be the harmonic.

You don't even need to take your finger off immediately after you play the harmonic - which someone will probably tell you. In fact, you can put that finger back touching the string - at the node - and it won't make a scrap of difference. Why should it? The string isn't even vibrating at the node!

Don't spend money on a guitar just for its propensity to play harmonics. That's crazy.

Comment: I find that taking the finger off immediately sometimes helps a bit to make the harmonic ring clearer, esp. with artificial harmonics. Not sure why, but I think it has to do with the nice fact that you don't need to hit the harmonic exactly at the node. However if you're not 100% precise, you would make an agreeable harmonic and your finger would then mute it.

Comment: @Ramillies - would 'sloppy playing'  sum it up..?

Comment: This makes no sense based on physics, unless you are talking about making bright tone.

Comment: @ggcg - sorry, I don't understand the comment. Was it based on physics, or supposed to be based on physics? Talking about a bright tone? No, I'm talking about making clear harmonics. Please explain in simple terms what you consider doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are you talking about picking near the bridge or touching the node near the bridge?

Comment: @ggcg - quote: 'the closer to the bridge you pluck'. Touching a harmonic node near the bridge doesn't make a lot of sense - they sort of run out of being audible arond 70mm from the bridge.

Comment: Yes I agree.  But plucking near the bridge also doesn't make sense form a physics perspective as you are trying to isolate the harmonic and you haven't.  I'd say plucking by an anti node makes more sense.

Comment: @ggcg - that may well be true. However, if one is playing a series of harmonics on the same string, it's hardly a convenient way to play. It would be like Jaco's bass harmonic solo in Birdland - which is a nightmare, believe me. Each fretted harmonic needs a different node to aim for. Bad enough on fretted - ten times worse on fretless!

Comment: It's easy with a little practice.  And this op is about tuning rather than playing

Comment: @ggcg - do you play it?

Comment: I am confused by your comment

Comment: @Tim, I agree with your statement about the "fingerprint" but not the picking.  I think there is a bit if ambiguity in your statement.  If I pick the 12th (n = 2) fret harmonic close to the bridge I get a lot of n = 4 and probably higher.  I couldn't say that the n = 2 is really swamped out by it but it is noticeably higher pitch.  ALL harmonics with a node at 12 and w/o a node at the pick location will get excited.  In contrast picking at the 1/4 L point gives the loudest n = 2 excitation.

Comment: @Tim, so what is really meant by the statement "The closer to the bridge you pluck, the better defined will be any harmonic"?  This just isn't true.  And I'm not coming at the from theory.  I sat here with my classical and tried this out.  Plucking near the bridge created more of a mess, too many higher harmonics to hear the n = 2, imo.

Comment: @ggcg - I mentioned Birdland, and your comment said it's easy with a little practice. Thus I asked if you play Birdland. Off the question, but I asked anyway. Plucking near the bridge works for me. I'll grab a guitar later and double check. Maybe it's changed over the years!

Comment: @Tim, I'm sure it will "work" but that isn't the point.  You proposed technique will necessarily produce a spectrum other than the harmonic you want, thus it isn't as helpful w/r to tuning as the OP is asking.  I think you want as close to a pure harmonic as you can get.

Comment: As for Jaco and burdland I think you are mixing apples and oranges.  The OP is clearly talking about the use of harmonics to tune and now you are talking about Jaco.  We can go in multiple directions with this.  I've played Birdland 100s of times but not the Bass.  However, I do move my picking hand with my fretting hand when thumbing to get the warmest sound possible (Wes style).  In general one must reposition the picking hand with newly fretted notes to ensure consistency of tone.  This is not a requirement for all tunes but something any pro would want to master.

Comment: ...And, I do a technique on classical that requires me to touch the harmonic with the right hand finger, while fretting the note, and plucking with my right hand thumb.  I think this is a far more complex and involved technique than locating the anti node and most of us can do it pretty fast.

Comment: @ggcg - I've used that technique for about 30 yrs. it works well on electric too.Although I touch with thumb and pluck with another finger. That allows somee more force to be applied as the string is plucked. Far more controllable. I wasn't on about 'playing Birdland' per se. I was on about the harmonics solo on bass -  I've played Birdland, on guitar, and keys, but that solo on fretless is in a different league than 'I've played Birdland'. Moving picking position came naturally after playing for ten yrs or so. I'm all over the place now, to achieve whatever tone I need!

Comment: @Tim, well, pulling your finger off makes it possible to save a sloppily played harmonic from going mute altogether and not doing it gives no advantage at all. Why not do it every time? Also if you have to play a long sequence of artificial harmonics, perhaps even playing two of them at once repeatedly at different places, I think you'd better be grateful that you don't need to hit everything with 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to get the loudest, most sustained harmonics

I've found that the volume and sustain of the harmonics correlates pretty directly with the volume and sustain of the instrument in general. Therefore, if you are looking only to play loud, distinct harmonics, I would recommend an electric guitar. Mix the neck and bridge pickups, with the volume and tone on the guitar nearly maxed out, and perhaps look for a guitar with humbuckers instead of single-coil pickups.

Position the amp so it faces at the guitar to generate a bit of feedback, and perhaps use moderate to heavy distortion if you are still dissatisfied with the level of sustain.

This produce fairly strong harmonics, not just at the 5th, 7th, and 12th frets, but also the subtler M3 harmonics near the 4th fret. But it isn't necessarily a very good tone, and having a lot of distortion won't enable you to hear the character of a perfect open chord tuned to its root's harmonics.

#### What I actually recommend

Your goal is to experiment with just intonation, so you don't necessarily need the loudest or even "best" harmonics. You just need harmonics that are audible enough to let you tune e.g. your B string to the Pythagorean major 3rd of a G, then play open G chords to hear the difference with equal temperament.

So, rather than getting a(nother?) new instrument, I would focus on improving your ears and fingers. Listen closely to the harmonics you are currently and try to identify what's wrong with them. If they sound muted, you are applying too much pressure with your fingers. If they sound indistinct (in pitch), it's an issue of horizontal placement. Bear in mind that the true location of the M3 harmonic is not over the 4th fret, but slightly below it, since the M3 interval in equal temperament runs sharp.

After getting your harmonic technique down, if you are tuning the B string to the M3 harmonic of the G and still find that the M3 harmonic is too quiet, I'd recommend just playing the open B string quieter too, instead of trying to amplify the harmonic itself. You don't have to play loud to tell whether two notes are in tune.

Comment: Use the nek pick up? When I do that, particularly on my Telecaster, it defeats one harmonic, because the node for that (on an open string) is exactly over that pick up. So it doesn't work!

Comment: The pickup shouldn't be directly under the node! Normally it's placed slightly away from the node to capture more overtones. Also note that a *harmonic* that you play and the physical *harmonics* of a vibrating string are related, but not identical, concepts. But on second thought, I think blending pickups would be the best way to ensure a variety of possible harmonics. Will edit.

Comment: It's a Fender Tele, early '70s I think. Years ago, I couldn't work out why somtimes natural harmonics wouldn't be heard. Reason is simple - the neck pup **IS** directly under the 3rd (or 4th)  harm. The second octave above the open string. Using both pups means it gets hears. Not sure if it's there on most guitars - it's where fret 24 would be, but it does happen on several other of my guitars.

Comment: I took a look at my guitar (a fake strat) and the neck pickup is about 5mm to the right of where the 24th fret would be. The 24th fret isn't just a location of a node for the 12th fret harmonic--it's also a location for the nodes of many of the harmonic modes of the open string itself. If your pup is directly under the 24th fret (which I suppose could be desirable to some), it won't pick up any of the modes that are multiples of four. OTOH, it shouldn't silence the 12th fret harmonic completely. That harmonic also has odd-numbered modes that will vibrate over the 24th fret.

Comment: A node refers to a place along the string that remains still *in that harmonic mode of the string's vibration* (in that basic solution of the wave equation). But in a real physical context, all of the modes are active to one extent or another, so there is no point along the string that is actually still (other than the endpoints). When you play a harmonic, you suppress the modes that don't have nodes at the site of the harmonic, but all of the other points along the string will move.

Comment: So how come I play a harmonic, and can touch that node many times, and the string still vibrates. Touch it even a millimetre away, and it stops.

Comment: When you play a harmonic, you fix *that point* on the string (and other integer multiples of that length), but the rest of the string vibrates. So playing a 12th fret harmonic stops motion at the 12th fret, but not at the 24th. This is for the same reason that when you pluck an open string there is motion at the 12th fret (from modes 1, 3, 5...) even though the 12th fret is a "node" of modes 2, 4, 6... A 12th fret harmonic cuts out the odd-numbered modes associated with the open string's frequency, but notice that the 12th fret harmonic includes mode #6, which has a peak at the 24th fret.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108444/discussion-between-max-and-tim).

Comment: @Max, neck pick ups are under a node, but that is what makes them warm.

Answer (score 0):

Among guitars, I'd say any cheap acoustic guitar with heavy roundwound strings will produce comparatively loud harmonics.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the "harmonics" you generate by attacking the strings properly are a property of the string.  In my opinion they are not necessarily "easy" to produce.  Also, if you use "harmonics" alone then your equal tempered notes will fall out of alignment so there is a bit of a compromise to make.

You excite the harmonic by touching the string at a node and then plucking it, preferably at an anti node.  You can also excite them by hammering the string correctly.  Once excited you want to know which guitar brand produce the "best" harmonics and provide some criterion for "best".  The ease of excitement would be more related to the set up and quality of string, and well as your training, than anything else.  It should be just as "easy" to excite a harmonic on a cheap guitar as on a $10,000 hand made arch top or Remirez.  Which brings me to the next point, sustain.  Acoustic guitars will differ with respect to sustain and this may correlate with quality.  But if you're playing electric then you can get whatever sustain you want with a good amp+effects set up.  In the world of electric guitars one could argue that the guitar is no longer the instrument.  Regardless, a good set up will produce good, long lasting harmonics.  If you are having trouble getting a good sound for the harmonics then it could be technique.  If you don't touch the string (and release that touch) just right you get nothing.  On the other hand once you figure out the right touch and timing you can make it ring every time.